# Understanding how も works in 一刻も早い

Tags: particle-も

I'm trying to understand the sentence

> **一刻も早い**解決を望みますね

but the bolded is throwing me off. Here I'm assuming "一刻も早い" is 一刻 + も + 早い, and here も is throwing me off.

I'm used to thinking of "も" as conveying things like "also", "additional", or "even though". So under this viewpoint:

- **一刻:** "moment"
- **も:** "additional"
- **早い:** "is-quick"

So I'm tempted to parse this as "additional-moment-is-quick", though this doesn't make much sense.

**Question:** What does the も convey after 一刻? How would the meaning of the sentence change if the も was omitted, or if 一刻は was used instead?  E.g.

1. **一刻も早い:** ?
2. **一刻は早い:** "as for a moment, is-quick"?
3. **一刻早い:** "quick moment"?

Answer (score 4):

The も is close to *even (though)*. as hiroki's answer suggests, it is usually でも as in 子供でも分かる (Even a child can understand (let alone grown-ups)).

Another thing is that 早い here is *early/earlier*.

So, 一刻も早く literally means *earlier even by 一刻* (+ if it is earlier by days, it is better), which translates to more idiomatic *asap*.

Though it shouldn't be relevant, [刻](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%88%BB) does not have a fixed length but is something like 15 - 40 mins.

Comment: Yes. 一刻 very short time. 一刻 feels a few minutes today. :-)

Comment: Why 一刻も早く not 一刻でも早く? I think 「でも」 is too long same as  "as soon as possible" becomes "ASAP". :-)

Comment: Do you know why 早い ("even by a moment, **more is-quick**") was used in the original sentence, rather than 早く ("even by a moment, **more quickly**")?

Comment: Is this a good (literal) translation of the original sentence (一刻も早い解決を望みますね)? *"Even (for as long as) a moment, we desire an is-more-quick[-than-that] resolution"*.

Comment: Re 早い/早く, it was just my misreading though both work. 早い as an adjective modifying 解決; 早く works as well because 解決 can be understood as a verb 解決する modified by adverb 早く. Re translation, I think it should be *even for as short as a moment*, other than that it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

In this sentence も is not dditional も. This も can be replaced with でも. 「一刻も早く」 means 「as soon as possible」